# How can I get dateCreated in Has-Many Relation in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain classes:

```
class A {
 hasMany = [bs : B]

}

class B { }
```

Note that B has no backward relation to a. GORM creates a join table in my MYSQL database `a_b`. This table has two columns the id of a and the id of b.

**How can I get a `dateCreated`in the join table?**

Comment: Create a model of the join table yourself and add whatever properties you want on it.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore please pst a full answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model of the join table yourself and add whatever properties you want on it. Simple, and done.

For example:

```
class A {
  static hasMany = [bs: JoinB]
}

class JoinB {
  static belongsTo = [a: A]
  B b
  Date dateCreated

  static mapping = {
    autoTimestamp true // default, but I like to be explicit about it.
  }
}

class B {
  String whatever
}
```

(Careful of typos etc. I just did that off the top of my head)

Comment: You do not need autoTimestamp true it is true by default.

Comment: I think with your solution it is the same as in my case. I suppose a new join table will be created called ``a_joinB`` because there is no back reference to A.

Comment: However, in my example you now have an explicit model of the join which you can add data such as dateCreated or whatever, regardless of the `a_joinB` Given that `B` could have been created any other time.

Comment: I think you miss the belongsTo.

Comment: But still it is not very good Because when you do ``a.bs``you do not get an Array of Bs you get an array of JoinBs.

Comment: `a.bs.collect { it.b }` works just fine too. You are going to suffer some penalty by customizing the collection, since you want to model more than just a relationship. You want the relationship and some extra stuff, therefore it becomes an entity into itself. Trade offs in an object oriented world and the way Hibernate automatically creates the data structures for modeling JUST a relationship.